# rounding down on varchar input

Tags: mysql, rounding, varchar

I was making some SQL calculations and found a very strange behavior.
When i `ROUND` the result of 2 fields it was rounded Down instead of UP.

I checked the data types .. one is `double` and one is `varchar` (don't ask).
Never the less the behavior is strange I don't find a logical reason for it:

```
select ROUND(3.17 *  450 , 2); /* = 1426.50 */
select ROUND(3.17 * '450', 2); /* = 1426.50 */

select ROUND(3.17 *  450 ); /* = 1427 */
select ROUND(3.17 * '450'); /* = 1426 !? */
```

The order of the params does not play a role.
Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: This might be similar to the last example for [round](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round). The `SELECT ROUND(2.5), ROUND(25E-1);` query returns different results.

Comment: No matter method you use I would not rely on implicit casting. Try :`select ROUND(3.17 * CAST('450' AS DECIMAL(10,4)));`